# Кто такой Конек-горбунок?

Tags: литература

Тут уже обсуждалась Золотая Рыбка, а меня интересует другой сказочный персонаж - Конек-горбунок.
Со сказкой Ершова вообще много интересного. Хотя бы то, что после нее он не смог больше написать ничего путного, будто весь талант ушел на гениальную сказку. И все персонажи ее более-менее ясны: Жар-птица, Шамаханская царица, рыба-кит (как символ китов, на которым по ранним преданиям держалась Земля), а вот откуда взялся сам Конек? Ершов придумал этот образ, соединив в нем черты коня, осла и верблюда, или взял из фольклора? Возможно, изобразив Конька маленьким и по сравнению с другими лошадьми уродливым, Ершов хотел показать, что зачастую самый маленький и слабый оказывается самым сильным (аналогично толкиенскому Фродо).

Comment: Шамаханская царица в *Коньке-горбунке?*

Comment: http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/18639/литература-конек-горбунок-есть-ли-прототип-в-фольклоре Уже обсуждалось.